# Python 2 game coordinates class

Tags: python, python-2.7, coordinates

I wanted to create a x-y coordinate system even though this is supposed to be a text RPG as to keep track of where everything is. So, I was experimenting on making a function and test for that function that would let the character move on a x-y grid, however, no matter what I try, I cannot make it work. Here is the code:
    class Player:

```
    def movement(charactor_movement):
        proceed = 0
        if charactor_movement == "left":
            character.position_x = character.position_x - 1
            proceed = 1
        elif charactor_movement == "right":
            character.position_x = character.position_x + 1
            proceed = 1
        elif charactor_movement == "forward":
            character.position_y = character.position_y + 1
            proceed = 1
        elif charactor_movement == "backward" or charactor_movement == "back":
            character.position_y = character.position_y - 1
            proceed = 1
charactor = Player()
charactor.position_x = 0
charactor.position_y = 0
proceed = 0
while proceed == 0:
    print "You are at",
    print charactor.position_x,
    print"x and",
    print charactor.position_y,
    print"y."
    global charactor_movement
    charactor_movement = raw_input("Where are you going?")
    charactor.movement()
```

At this point, it does what it is supposed to do up to changing the coordinates, as it prints `"You are at 0 x and 0 y"` and `"Where are you going?"` no matter what I type. I have tried adding an `else` to the function which it defaulted to no matter what I typed and gave me `"Sorry, I cannot understand you."` Any comments on fixing or generally improving the code would be appreciated.*(Note: For the testing I purposely did not add a way to exit. The class is what i need fixed.)*

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the same coordinates with each iteration because your values within your `while` loop are not changing. Incrementing `character.position_x` within `movement` will never change the value of `character.position_x` within your `while` loop, as it is outside your function's [*scope*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules). You have to use the `global` keyword *within* your `movement` function for each variable you are changing should you want your current logic to remain the same. Additionally, why not just pass `charactor_movement` as a parameter to your `movement` function, as opposed to using `global` as you currently are doing.

---

## A minimal example:

Consider the following:

```
def somefunct(x):
    mycode = x
    
mycode = 'no codez'
while True:
    print mycode
    codez = raw_input('gimme teh codez: ')
    somefunct(codez)
```

which outputs

```
>>>[evaluate untitled-1.py]
no codez
gimme teh codez: codez!
no codez
```

Declaring `mycode` as `global` in the function places it ***in*** the scope of the `while` loop when assigned, thus

```
def somefunct(x):
    global mycode  #make variable global here
    mycode = x
        
mycode = 'no codez'
while True:
    print mycode
    codez = raw_input('gimme teh codez: ')
    somefunct(codez)
```

results in the output

```
>>>[evaluate untitled-1.py]
no codez
gimme teh codez: codez!
codez!
```